# llama-2-7b LLM Evaluation failing using Trulens

Tags: nlp, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to build a RAG system using llama_index, (gpt-3.5/Llama-7b) and truera on some dataset. Link [Used](https://learn.deeplearning.ai/building-evaluating-advanced-rag) for reference

**Scenario 1** : `Model : gpt-2.5-turbo`
While evaluating the model using gpt-3.5-turbo, I found no issue and can see the leaderboard as well.

**Scenario 2** `Model : meta/llama-2-7b-chat:8e6975e5ed6174911a6ff3d60540dfd4844201974602551e10e9e87ab143d81e`
While evaluating the same code using llama LLM, I get "*list index out of range*" when sending the output to TruLens dashboard.

Attaching a sample code for reference:

```
# Dataset
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["/content/drive/test.pdf"]).load_data()

# set the LLM
llama2_7b_chat = "meta/llama-2-7b-chat:8e6975e5ed6174911a6ff3d60540dfd4844201974602551e10e9e87ab143d81e"
Settings.llm = Replicate(
    model=llama2_7b_chat,
    temperature=0.01
)

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer


service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=Settings.llm, embed_model="local:BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"
)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents([document],service_context=service_context)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

response = query_engine.query(
    "What are the different kinds of user context?"
)
print(str(response))


### Evaluation using TruLens

eval_questions = [] # its a list of questions

# question from dataset:
new_question = "What is Geofencing?"
eval_questions.append(new_question)

print(eval_questions)

!pip install trulens-eval

from trulens_eval import TruLlama, Tru, Feedback, feedback

from trulens_eval.feedback import Groundedness
from trulens_eval import OpenAI

tru =Tru()

tru.reset_database()

openai = OpenAI()

def trulens_recorder(query_engine, app_id):
    tru_recorder = TruLlama(
        query_engine,
        app_id=app_id,
        feedbacks=feedbacks
        )
    return tru_recorder

tru_recorder = trulens_recorder(query_engine,
                                             app_id="LLAMA_Direct Query Engine")

#with tru_recorder as recording:
  for question in eval_questions:
    response = query_engine.query("What are the different kinds of user context?")
    print("Response: ", response)
```

On uncommenting the line `#with tru_recorder as recording:`, the code fails. Attaching a snapshot

[image]

However, if I replace the llama-7b model with gpt model, the code works smoothly.

[image]

I do understand that both these models have different structure underneath. But could that be the only reason its not able to integrate with evaluation tool like TruLens